# Improving concurrent AJAX file upload performance

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, ajax-upload

I have AJAX file upload in my website and it is very slow in case of concurrent file uploads. You can see the details here, [Concurent AJAX file upload LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455196/concurent-ajax-file-upload-limit). So i'm looking for  way to start my second AJAX request just after the first upload completes, but before the other operations complete(Like moving the file to S3, Creating Samples, DB operations etc.,). Because i'm thinking that the POSTed files only makes the browser overloads(Since the normal AJAX requests are very fast when compare). So, is my idea correct and is there any way to find when the upload completes even before the AJAX request completes?

Or otherwise is there anyway in Javascript to find the whether the Browser is overloaded already? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

you can use ajax in async mode false

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    // ...

});
```

this will prevent the next line to be fired before the ajax request is over

Better you can include some action in the success option :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
 async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    // do somethings after you receive the post results (data)
  }
```

});

Comment: Hi bleuscyther, Thanks r the answer. But this question is not about queueing the AJAX requests. But to find whether the values are posted before it ends i.e., even before the success event fires :)

Comment: True :), my bad, will be more careful next time :). Maybe you want to upload the files first and then do a last ajax() to process all of them ?